# How to tell Angular to get an input value from the DOM?

Tags: angular, dom

My job's SSO fill my login form from a way not compatible with Angular's form I need to fix.

The problem is the user see the form as filled by the SSO :

[image]

Angular's form see no value (top line on screenshot above), whereas if I directly request the DOM, the input is well supplied (I got the following snapshot with a breakpoint):

[image]

I don't know how the SSO is working internaly, is there a way to tell Angular form to get the real value from the DOM?

The form is writted like:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-input-container>
    <input matInput name="userName" type="name" placeholder="User" formControlName="userName" required />
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no SSO, so I suggest you try:

1. create the form in the own declaration instead of ngOnInit

   ```
   form=new FormGroup({
      userName:new FormControl('',Validators.required)
      ...
   })
   ```
2. You can also try use ngModel to give value to the formsControl
   instead of directly use formControlName

   ```
   <input matInput name="userName" type="name" placeholder="User" 
         [ngModel]="form.controls.userName.value"
         (ngModelChange)="form.controls.userName.setValue($event)"
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
   required />
   ```
3. Really you always can use setValue to give value to the form, but
   really I don't know where use. If I imagine in a (focus) event, and even enclosed in a setTimeout

   ```
   focus()
   {
     setTimeout(() => {
       const form: any = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
       Object.keys(this.form.value).forEach((key: string) => {
         const value: string = form.elements[key].value || '';
         this.form.get(key)?.value != value &&
         this.form.get(key)?.setValue(value);
       });
     })
   }
   ```

But really I can not check it if work

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-q35ymg?file=src%2Fmain.ts) with the third option

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help: [template reference](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables)